# Spring Boot CRUD operation to create web service configuration

Tags: java, spring, rest, spring-boot, web-services

I am new to using Spring Boot. I am trying to create a restful web service for the CRUD operations.

I have created model, repository and below files:
The service file:

```java
    import org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication;
    import org.springframework.boot.autoconfigure.SpringBootApplication;
    @SpringBootApplication
    public class EmployeeServiceApplication {
     public static void main(String[] args) {
        SpringApplication.run(EmployeeServiceApplication.class, args);
     }
    }
```

Controller file:

```
@RestController
public class Controller {

    @Autowired
    private EmployeeServiceDesc employeeService;

    @GetMapping("/employee/")
    public List<Employee> getAllEmployees() {
        return employeeService.getAllEmployees();
    }

    @GetMapping("/employee/{employeeId}")
    public Employee getEmployeeById(@PathVariable int employeeId) {
        return employeeService.getEmployeeById(employeeId);
    }

    @PostMapping("/employee/")
    public ResponseEntity<Void> add(@RequestBody Employee newEmployee, UriComponentsBuilder builder) {
        Employee employee = employeeService.addEmployee(newEmployee);
        if(employee == null) {
            return ResponseEntity.noContent().build();
        }
        HttpHeaders headers = new HttpHeaders();
        headers.setLocation(builder.path("/employee/{id}").buildAndExpand(employee.getId()).toUri());
        return new ResponseEntity<Void>(headers, HttpStatus.CREATED);
    }

    @PutMapping("/employee/")
    public ResponseEntity<Employee> updateEmployee(@RequestBody Employee v) {
        Employee employee = employeeService.getEmployeeById(v.getId());
        if(employee == null) {
            return new ResponseEntity<Employee>(HttpStatus.NOT_FOUND);
        }
        employee.setName(employee.getName());
        employee.setDOB(employee.getDOB());
        employee.setSalary(employee.getSalary());
        employeeService.updateEmployee(employee);
        return new ResponseEntity<Employee>(employee, HttpStatus.OK);
    }

    @DeleteMapping("/employee/{id}")
    public ResponseEntity<Employee> deleteEmployee(@PathVariable int id) {
        Employee employee = employeeService.getEmployeeById(id);
        if(employee == null) {
            return new ResponseEntity<Employee>(HttpStatus.FOUND);
        }
        employeeService.deleteEmployee(id);
        return new ResponseEntity<Employee>(HttpStatus.NO_CONTENT);
    }
}
```

When I send the request through Postman I am getting error : No found
I think I am missing some configuration but not sure which one am I supposed to do? Can anyone help me with this?

Comment: What is your request end-point you tested in Postman? Show detail error of request by Postman.

Comment: And do you have any errors/exceptions in the logs?

Comment: please share the screenshot of the postman request/response

Comment: Everything here looks fine - you'll need to provide an example failing endpoint you're trying in postman.

Answer (score 0):

You should have something like below  (You should have map the request)

```
@RestController
@RequestMapping("/")
public class Controller {
......
....
..
}
```

```
@RestController
@RequestMapping("/api")
public class Controller {
}
```

> After Comment not working

spring-boot will scan for components in packages below com.x.x., so if your controller is in com.x.x you need to scan for it explicitly

```
@SpringBootApplication
@ComponentScan(basePackageClasses = Controller.class) // you should be able to justified as your packages structure 
    public class EmployeeServiceApplication {
     public static void main(String[] args) {
        SpringApplication.run(EmployeeServiceApplication.class, args);
     }
    }
```

Comment: Can you try which I have updated code after comment

Answer (score 0):

You dont necessarily need @RequestMapping for you service to be exposed. I believe here the issue is because of the '/' at the end of your mapping. Try replacing

```
@GetMapping("/employee/")
```

with

```
@GetMapping("/employee")
```